# How to add (or subtract) two exponential components with same base?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I am to solve for $x$ using logs: $e^{2x}-e^x-110=0$

During my steps, I'm unsure how to combine $e^{2x}-e^x$ into one. My attempt:

$$e^{2x}-e^x-110=0$$
$$e^{2x}-e^x=110$$
Here's where I get confused:
$$\ln(e^{2x}-e^x)=\ln(110)$$
$$2x-x=\ln(110)$$
$$x=\ln(110)$$

My textbook says the solution is $\ln11$.

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at $\ln11$?

More specifically, how can I simplify this line on the left of the equals sign? $e^{2x}-e^x=110$

Comment: In the second to last step it looks like you implied that $\ln(e^{2x}-e^x)=\ln(e^{2x})-\ln(e^x)$. That is not always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brother, I know you're smart enough that you know quadratic equations,
Here in your question it is asked that :
*\exp(2x)-exp(x)=110*
You can subsitute *\exp(x)=u*
And by the knowledge of exponentials we know
*\exp(2x)= u^{2}*
which gives us :
*\u^{2}-u=110*
then you can solve this equations easily then when you get to value of u, break u into *\exp(x)* and then you can take the logarithm and get the value of x.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** let $y=e^x$, and solve a quadratic first.

--

On where you went wrong, note $\log(a \pm b) = \log(a) \pm \log(b)$ does **not** hold true.

Comment: Could you expand on this? This solution has lots of upvotes which has the effect of making me feel even more dumb. I'm not looking for a hint, I'm looking for a solution with steps on how to get there so that I can then reinforce it in the subsequent exercises.

Comment: @DougFir You need to try the hint yourself, and then let me know where you get stuck if youre unable to proceed.  I suppose you know how to solve a quadratic such as $y^2-y-110=0$, which is what you get after the substitution I hinted.

Comment: Why would 2x become y^2?

Comment: $2x$ doesn't become $y^2$. Unless your write out what you're doing, others cannot help you. $e^{2x}=(e^x)^2=y^2$.

Comment: Note my post says 'Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at $ln11$?' I'm looking for a hint or some other condescending 'nudge'. Can you answer my question and explain it or not?

Comment: @DougFir Actually, i have done both already in the post above. Unless you attempt yourself and tell exactly where you're stuck, I can't help you any further.

Answer (score 2):

Your error starts here:

$$\ln (e^{2x}-e^x)=2x-x$$

This can be at least logarithmic equation, but not a logarithmic equality.

The correct rule is as follows:

$$\ln (e^{2x}\times e^{x})=\ln e^{2x}+\ln e^x=2x+x$$

Because, this is *not* a logarithmic equality:

$$\ln (a+b)=\ln a+\ln b$$

But remember that,

$$\ln(ab)=\ln a+\ln b$$

is an obvious logarithmic equality.

---

For the correct solution method, you can use the substitution $e ^ x = t$.

You will get,

$$t^2-t-110=0.$$