# Use one-to-one property of logs to find an exact solution for $\ln 5+\ln(5x^2-5)=\ln 56$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am to solve $\ln5+\ln(5x^2-5)=\ln56$ using the one to one property of logs. According to my textbook the solution is $\pm\frac{9}{5}$ whereas I got $\sqrt{\frac{56}{5}}$

My working:

$$\ln5+\ln(5x^2-5)=\ln56$$
$$5x^2-5+5=56$$
$$5x^2=56$$
$$x^2=\frac{56}{5}$$
$$x=\sqrt{\frac{56}{5}}$$
$$~3.35$$

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at $\pm\frac{9}{5}$?

Comment: Your first step is invalid. What rule says $\log A+\log B=\log C$ implies $A+B=C$? Use instead $\log 5 + \log (5x^2  - 5) = \log (5(5x^2  - 5))$.

Comment: Your error is that $\ln 5 +\ln(x^2-5)=\ln\bigl(5(x^2-5)\bigr)$.

Comment: Your question/error is almost the same and  we answered before. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4131745/how-to-add-or-subtract-two-exponential-components-with-same-base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln a+\ln b=\ln c$ does not imply $a+b=c$, i.e. $\ln$ does not distribute over addition. Instead it implies $ab=c$:
$$5(5x^2-5)=56$$
$$x^2-1=\frac{56}{25}$$
$$x^2=\frac{81}{25}\implies x=\pm\frac95$$